# HTTPS links to imgur doesn't work for me

Tags: bug, images

It seems [HTTP imgur links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5188364/55075) are forced from HTTP to HTTPS, however HTTPS doesn't seems to work for me.

The following images doesn't load for me.

Example 1:

[image: result]

Example 2:

[image: result]

This is what I see:

[image]

[image]

Although HTTP works fine (for the same IP).

I've tested on local, but `i.imgur.com` isn't responding to https:

```
$ telnet i.imgur.com https
Trying 151.101.60.193...
telnet: connect to address 151.101.60.193: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
$ dig i.imgur.com
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;i.imgur.com.           IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
i.imgur.com.        26790   IN  CNAME   prod.imgur.map.fastlylb.net.
prod.imgur.map.fastlylb.net. 1  IN  A   151.101.60.193
$ sudo mtr 151.101.60.193
Host             
1. 192.168.15.1  
2. ???
3. 10.254.254.162
4. 10.254.254.178
5. ???
```

I've tested on another server, it works, but points to different IP, but same IP works as well:

```
$ telnet i.imgur.com https
Trying 151.101.12.193...
Connected to prod.imgur.map.fastlylb.net.
$ telnet 151.101.60.193 https
Trying 151.101.60.193...
Connected to 151.101.60.193.
```

Is there any network or DNS issue? Or my IP is blocked from somewhere.

Comment: Are you trying to load these from your home, or from your work address? Could these be blocked by a proxy where you are? (They're loading just fine for me)

Comment: From home, I'm not using any proxy.

Comment: HTTPS doesn't work, HTTP does work for the same IP via telnet, so probably it's not IP based.

Comment: If there *is* a DNS or routing issue, then ultimately only imgur or your ISP can fix it (depending on the proble), and you'd have to report it to them; it *should* just work...

Comment: Doesn't seems like routing or DNS issue since: `telnet i.imgur.com http` - works, `telnet i.imgur.com https` doesn't work as per _Operation timed out_ (same via IP: `151.101.60.193`). So could be some CDN access issue for specific imgur IP address.

Comment: What location/ISP are you having an issue accessing from? This looks like :443 being blocked somewhere in the pipe.

Comment: @NickCraver `83.216.95.*` (London, UK)

Comment: Just to clarify: you're saying *Imgur* doesn't work, and not `i.stack.imgur.com` (our domain)? We are on a separate private instance, on a different CDN as well.

Comment: `imgur.com:https` and `i.stack.imgur.com:https` works fine, `i.imgur.com:https` doesn't, if `i.imgur.com` isn't Stack domain, then that's fine, but still stack is replacing http from the post (which is working) with https which doesn't work.

Comment: @kenorb They do work...but not for you, which is what we're trying to determine the cause of. Can you reach https://stackoverflow.com by chance?

Comment: @NickCraver Yes, SO over HTTPS works fine.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284819/your-connection-to-this-site-is-not-private